# How to merge two alike items within the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I have 1 superclass DessertItem. Which has 4 subclasses Candy, Cookie, Ice Cream, Sundae. The Sundae class extends the Ice Cream class. Superclass is an abstract class. I also have a separate class which does not belong to the superclass, but in the same package - Order. There is another class - DessertShop, where the main is located.

Candy, Cookie classes implement SameItem<> generic class. The generic interface SameItem<> class looks like this:

```
public interface SameItem<T> {
    public boolean isSameAs(T other);
}
```

The Candy, Cookie classes have this method:

```
@Override
public boolean isSameAs(Candy other) {
    if(this.getName() == other.getName() && this.getPricePerPound() == other.getPricePerPound()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

And something similar, but for the cookie class.

All the subclasses have these methods :
default constructor,

```
public Cookie(String n, int q, double p) {
    super(n);
    super.setPackaging("Box");
    cookieQty = q;
    pricePerDozen = p;

    }

    public int getCookieQty() {
        return cookieQty;
    }

    public double getPricePerDozen() {
        return pricePerDozen;
    }
    
    public void setCookieQty(int q) {
    cookieQty = q;
    }
    
    public void setToppingPricePricePerDozen(double p) {
        pricePerDozen = p;
    }
    @Override
    public double calculateCost() {
        double cookieCost = cookieQty * (pricePerDozen/12);
        return cookieCost;
        
    }
```

and toString() method

So, what my program does is gets the input from the User, asks the name of the dessert, asks the quantity, or the quantity according to the dessert, ask the unit price. Asks the payment method. And then prints the receipt. This how the Order class looks like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Order extends implements Payable{
    //attributes
    PayType payMethod;
    private ArrayList<DessertItem> OrderArray;


//Constructor
public Order() {
    OrderArray = new ArrayList<>();
    payMethod = PayType.CASH;
}


//methods
public ArrayList<DessertItem> getOrderList(){
    
    return OrderArray;
    
}// end of getOrderList
public ArrayList<DessertItem> Add(DessertItem addDesert){
enter code here

    OrderArray.add(addDesert);
        /* for(DessertItem i : getOrderList()) {

            if(i instanceof Candy) {
                for(DessertItem j : getOrderList()) {
                    if(j instanceof Candy) {
                        if(((Candy) i).isSameAs((Candy) j)) {
 */
//this is what I have tried so far, but I am lost
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if(i instanceof Cookie) {
            for (DessertItem j : getOrderList()) {
                if(((Cookie) i).isSameAs((Cookie)j)) {
                    OrderArray.add(j);
                } else {
                OrderArray.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    }

    return OrderArray;
}// end of Add


public int itemCount(){
    int counted = OrderArray.size();
    return counted;
}//end of itemCount


public double orderCost() {
    double orderResult = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<OrderArray.size(); i++) {
        orderResult = orderResult + OrderArray.get(i).calculateCost();
    }
    return orderResult;
}
public double orderTax() {
    double taxResult = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<OrderArray.size(); i++) {
        taxResult = taxResult + OrderArray.get(i).calculateTax();
    }
    return taxResult;
}
public double orderTotal() {
    double ordertotal = orderTax() + orderCost();
    return ordertotal;
}





@Override
public  PayType getType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return payMethod;
}


@Override
public void setPayType(PayType p) {
    payMethod = p;
    
}

public String toString() {
    
    String finalOutput = "";
    finalOutput += "------------------------Receipt--------------------------\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < OrderArray.size(); i++) {
        finalOutput = finalOutput + OrderArray.get(i).toString();
    }
    finalOutput += "--------------------------------------------------\n";

    String line2 = "Total Number of items in order: " + itemCount() + "\n";
    String line3 = String.format("Order Subtotals:\t\t\t\t $%-6.2f", orderCost());
    String line4 = String.format("[Tax: $%.2f]\n", orderTax());
    String line5 = String.format("\nOrder Total:\t\t\t\t\t $%-6.2f\n", orderTotal());
    String outputVar = String.format("%s\n%s%s%17s", line2, line3, line4, line5);
    String ending = "----------------------------------------------------";
    String payType = String.format("\nPaid for with: %s", payMethod.name());
    return finalOutput + outputVar + ending + payType;
}
```

So, my question is, how can I combine like items into one item?

Comment: Are you supposed to check for duplicate items being added to an order? That would be odd, I don't know of a restaurant that won't let you order the same thing from a menu twice.

Comment: Why does the `Order` class extend `DesertItem`? Is it so that you can add one `Order` to another? If so that's a code smell. You should instead have a method that specifically takes an `Order` instance, something like `public Order addOrder(Order other) { ... }` and make sure to check if `other == this`.

Comment: Wait, are you just trying to check if two dessert items are equal?  Why don't you just implement hashcode and equals?

Comment: @JonnyHenly, it does not extend it in my original code. I was just trying everything out of despair and just tried to extend it to see if that would help. I forgot to erase that part before copy-pasting my code. They are not two different orders. I am trying to combine two similar items withing the ArrayList. I know that they are similar, but How do I merge them? Like I order 2lb of candies for 2$ hit the enter. And then I remember that I need 1 lb more of the same candies. And I order that remaining 1 lb to the same order. How do I merge those items in the receipt?

Comment: @AmirAfghani, No I know that they are equal. Being equal how do I merge them within the ArrayList?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that.  If you follow my advice and override hashcode and equals, you can use a container that doesn't allow for duplicates like a Set, and then just convert that to a list after processing..  You realize your SameItem interface basically is re-inventing the wheel, right?

Comment: All of your other code should still work if you just add a 1lb order of candies to the order. What if someone is specifically ordering 1lb and 2lbs of candy, suppose the order is for two people, you wouldn't want to give them 3lbs of candy and have them separate it.